# Soap UI ad an Node to Request (Groovy)

Tags: groovy, soapui, appendchild

i got a Problem.

So i got an WSDL like this:

```
     <node1>
        <subnode1>data</subnode1>
        <subnode2>data</subnode2>

        <subnode3>data</subnode3>
        <subnode4>data</subnode4>

        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <subnode5>
           <subsubnode1>data</subsubnode1>
           <subsubnode2>data</subsubnode2>
           <subsubnode3>data</subsubnode3>
        </subenode5>
     </node1>
```

for Testing via SoapUI, the Problem is now, that the subnode5 can have one ore more reptions, it depends from the Database. Now my questions - how can isolved this to make the repetitions dynamic.

so i try t append the subnode5 via a groovy script like this:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder;
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils;

def groovyUtil = new GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtil.getXmlHolder( "name#Request" )
def parentnode  = holder.getDomNode( "//node1" )

def text    = '''
            <subnode5>
             <subsubnode1>data</subsubnode1>
             <subsubnode2>data</subsubnode2>
             <subsubnode3>data</subsubnode3>
            </subnode5>
           '''.stripMargin()

 def nodetext = groovyUtil.getXMLHolder( text )
 def nodeItem = nodetext.getDomNode ( "//subnode5")
 parentnode.appendChild(nodeItem, true)
 holder.updateProperty()
```

but i get an errormessage:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj.appendChild() is applicable for argument types: (org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj, java.lang.Boolean) values: [?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                  , ...] Possible solutions: appendChild(org.w3c.dom.Node) error at line: 29

what i will is added a new child to the request

```
  <node1>
    <subnode1>data</subnode1>
    <subnode2>data</subnode2>

    <subnode3>data</subnode3>
    <subnode4>data</subnode4>

    <subnode5>
       <subsubnode1>data</subsubnode1>
       <subsubnode2>data</subsubnode2>
       <subsubnode3>data</subsubnode3>
    </subenode5>
    --first repition--
    <subnode5>
       <subsubnode1>data</subsubnode1>
       <subsubnode2>data</subsubnode2>
       <subsubnode3>data</subsubnode3>
    </subenode5>
   --second repition--
    <subnode5>
       <subsubnode1>data</subsubnode1>
       <subsubnode2>data</subsubnode2>
       <subsubnode3>data</subsubnode3>
    </subenode5>
    .... and so on 
 </node1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a roadmap - you will need to adjust it to suit your particular needs!

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils

// create groovyUtils and XmlHolder for request
def grUtils = new GroovyUtils(context)
def requestHolder = grUtils.getXmlHolder("name#Request")

// find the Node that I am interested in
def requestNode = requestHolder.getDomNode("//*:node1")
// the Document object is used to create new nodes
def requestDoc = requestNode.getOwnerDocument()

// create the whole structure 3 times
3.times {

    // create a new Element in the Document
    def subelement5 = requestDoc.createElement("subnode5")
    def subnode5 = requestNode.insertBefore(subelement5, requestNode.getFirstChild())

    // create the sub-sub nodes
    1..3.each {
        def subsubelement = requestDoc.createElement("subsubnode${it}")
        subnode5.insertBefore(subsubelement, subnode5.getFirstChild())
        // add in the data text
        subsubelement.appendChild(requestDoc.createTextNode("data"))
    }
}

// write the Document out to the request
requestHolder.updateProperty(true)
```

Here is some [additional reading](https://siking.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/dynamically-create-elements-in-a-soapui-request/), if interested.