# SOAPUI - Add Children Nodes to Request Based on Conditions

Tags: xml, web-services, groovy, soapui, xmlbeans

I'm working on a SOAP service to add documents to case. Some of these documents require metadata that should be sent with the request otherwise it will fail. So based on this condition, request should be updated dynamically. 
I parse response of validation service that returns mandatory document, then pass these parameters to add documents service. 
The part of the request I want to change is the number of entries inside the request below, for example if there should be two types of metadata for a document, then the map element should contain two entry elements, and so on

```
<listOfDocuments>
    <documentProperties>
        <map>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <entry>
                <key>?</key>
                <value>?</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </documentProperties>
<listOfDocuments>
```

I've tried the following with groovy but I keep getting an error that I can't work around , in the following code I'm trying to add the entry element into the first document object ( listOfDocuments[1] )

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def entryNode = """<entry>
                   <key></key>
                   <value></value>
                 </entry> """
def paresedENode= new XmlSlurper().parseText(entryNode)

def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "Add Documents#Request" )
def parentNode  = holder.getDomNode( "//listOfDocuments[1]/documentProperties/map" )
parentNode.appendNode( paresedENode )
```

I get the following syntax error that i can't work around

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj.appendNode() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild) values: [] error at line: 43
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Soap UI ad an Node to Request (Groovy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148600/soap-ui-ad-an-node-to-request-groovy)

Comment: Seems when you use `parentNode.appendNode( paresedENode )`, you're trying to mix XmlBeans objects and XmlSlurper objects. Even if they're both nodes, you cannot insert the former into the latter or viceversa. Look at this [blog post](https://siking.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/dynamically-create-elements-in-a-soapui-request/) and also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29150207/9015852). Let me know if that helps