# how can i clone existing dome node in an xml request

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

**i have an existing xml request like this** :

```
<ns2:vehicles>
    <ns2:cars>
        <ns2:suvs>
            <ns2:property>
                <ns2:isExist></ns2:isExist>
            </ns2:property>
            <ns2:Brand BrandName="Volvo" Model="XC 40"/>
        </ns2:suvs>
    </ns2:cars>
</ns2:vehicles>
```

**I want to add another suvs dome to this request and in the end it should look like this** :

```
<ns2:vehicles>
    <ns2:cars>
        <ns2:suvs>
            <ns2:property>
                <ns2:isExist></ns2:isExist>
            </ns2:property>
            <ns2:Brand BrandName="Volvo" Model="XC 40"/>
        </ns2:suvs>
        <ns2:suvs>
            <ns2:property>
                <ns2:isExist></ns2:isExist>
            </ns2:property>
            <ns2:Brand BrandName="BMW" Model="X5"/>
        </ns2:suvs>
    </ns2:cars>
</ns2:vehicles>
```

**I tried this :**

```
def nextStep = myTestCase.getTestStepAt(context.currentStepIndex + 1)         
XmlHolder requestHolder = new XmlHolder(nextStep.name)
void cloneNodes(int iterationNumber, String nodePath, XmlHolder requestHolder) {

    rowTotal.times {
        def CarsNode= requestHolder.getDomNode("(" + nodePath + ")[last()]")
        CarsNode.getParentNode().insertBefore(CarsRequest.cloneNode(true),
                CarsNode.getNextSibling())
    }
}
```

But this throws "**ERROR: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Content is not allowed in prolog.**" error. Any idea about how to clone the nodes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Soap UI ad an Node to Request (Groovy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148600/soap-ui-ad-an-node-to-request-groovy)

Comment: Yest it did, thank you!